# How to filter a stream in Flutter based on one of its attributes?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

I have this bloc which streams a Response of Products:

```
class ProductModelBloc {
  ProductModel _productModelRepository;
  StreamController<Response<Product>> _productListController =
  new BehaviorSubject();

  StreamSink<Response<Product>> get productListSink =>
  _productListController.sink;

  Stream<Response<Product>> get productListStream =>
  _productListController.stream;

  ProductModelBloc() {
    _productModelRepository = ProductModel();
    fetchProduct();
}

  fetchProduct() async {
    productListSink.add(Response.loading('Getting Products'));
    try {
      Product products =
      await _productModelRepository.getProductsBySeller(sellerId: 2);
      productListSink.add(Response.completed(products));
    } catch (e) {
      productListSink.add((Response.error(e.toString())));
      print(e);
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _productListController?.close();
  }
}
```

Say instead of only getting all the products I want to add a filter so that I can get products based on their `categoryId`. How would it be done?

This is the Response class:

```
class Response<T> {
  Status status;
  T data;
  String message;

  Response.loading(this.message) : status = Status.LOADING;
  Response.completed(this.data) : status = Status.COMPLETED;
  Response.error(this.message) : status = Status.ERROR;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Status : $status \n Message : $message \n Data : $data";
  }
}

enum Status { LOADING, COMPLETED, ERROR }
```

Comment: You want to send that filter to server or apply that filter locally when you get all the results back ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I want to apply it locally

Comment: @pskink I tried it but didn't work because it returns a list while the stream expects a `Response<Product>`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the categoryId in your fetchProduct method and do the filtering in that method itself.

```
fetchProduct({bool applyFilter = false, int categoryId}) async {
  productListSink.add(Response.loading('Getting Products'));
  try {
    Product products =
    await _productModelRepository.getProductsBySeller(sellerId: 2);

    if (applyFilter) {
      Product filteredProducts = // Write filtering logic here;
      productListSink.add(Response.completed(filteredProducts));
    } else {
      productListSink.add(Response.completed(products));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    productListSink.add((Response.error(e.toString())));
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Note: you don't have to use that bool also, you can check whether the categoryId is null or not.

Comment: I tried to implement it but now I'm facing another issue. I keep getting this error 
`type '_MapStream<Response<Product>, Iterable<Data>>' is not a subtype of type 'Product' in type cast` 
after implementing this 
`Product filteredProducts = _productListController.stream.map((productsList) => productsList.data.data.where((product) => product.attributes.categoryId == categoryId)) as Product;`. 
I'm not sure how to solve it because this is as far as I know the only way to retrieve the `categoryId`

Comment: @Mohamed Why are you using prod `_productListController.stream.` , just above the filtering comment (That I've marked), you have product data in your hand. you can filter using that product object right ?